# Website Form Validation

Tags: php, mysql, html, validation

I am currently designing a website and database solution which allows an administrator to login and view/add/edit/delete data held in the database.

What is the best way to go about form validation for details the person will enter into these forms;

i.e. dates must have the convention xx/xx/xx

Comment: For client side validation I recommend http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/

Comment: Thats a fantastic resource, will give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways of validating such data but the most popular one is using [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). You probably also want to check other things after validating the data format.

For instance if you want to check your date you can do the following:

```
function checkDateFormat($date)
{
//match the format of the date
  if (preg_match ("/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})$/", $date, $parts)) {
  //check weather the date is valid of not
    if(checkdate($parts[2],$parts[3],$parts[1]))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This will not only check the format of the date (in this case yyyy/mm/dd but you can modify it slightly to support yy/mm/dd or whichever order you want) but also will check if it is a valid date (e.g. 2001/02/31 is not a valid date).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this native or by libraries like.

Native:

```
//If form was submitted  
if ($_POST['submitted']==1) {  
  // check date format, ...
  if ($_POST[date]){  
    $date = $_POST[date]; //If date was entered  
  }  
  ...
}
```

Or by library:  http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2

```
<?php
require_once 'HTML/QuickForm2.php';
require_once 'HTML/QuickForm2/Rule/Required.php';
require_once 'HTML/QuickForm2/Rule/Regex.php';

$form = new HTML_QuickForm2('tutorial');
$username = $form->addElement('text', 'username');
$form->addElement('submit', null, array('value' => 'Send!'));

$username->addRule(new HTML_QuickForm2_Rule_Required(
    $username, 'Username is required!'
));
....
```

Comment: Some more informations: http://www.montanaprogrammer.com/learn-php/advanced-php-form-validation/

Comment: Your solution only explains how to check if a required field was entered

Comment: there was asked for validation with the example of date "i.e. dates must have the convention xx/xx/xx". So there will be more fields with other data to validate. I gave a example for a set field.